# Why does my CSS selector not identify these elements correctly?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a style but am having trouble identifying a class of element identified by an ID such as `airbus.errors` (first example) or `boeing.errors` (second example below).

```
<div class="message">
  <span id="airbus.errors">
</div>
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
.message .errors
{
  background: red;
}
```

I need to write it generically so that it would also work with this case:

```
<div class="message">
  <span id="boeing.errors">
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just set `class="errors"`?

Comment: As I said in a comment below the contents of the span are not set by me so I have to assume that it will always be an id with a value of `something.errors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `.message .errors` it's looking for an element with a class `message` and descendants with a class `errors` which doesn't match your HTML

Try this instead:

```
.message #boeing-errors
{
    background: red;
}
```

or just

```
#boeing-errors
{
    background: red;
}
```

since `#boing-errors` is an ID and should be unique.

**Note that in CSS the `.` character is reserved for class names**

If you have no control of this ID being output you can't use it since the ID has a `.` in it. You can do this, but it might be too generic:

```
.message > span { background: red; }
```

---

Here's another question on SO for valid css characters: [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)

Comment: Thanks but that won't identify the `airbus.errors` element - it needs to work for both.

Comment: That ID is invalid for CSS, so you're in a bit of a pickle

Comment: Thanks - the right arrow selector (whatever that's called) works fine. How is that different from saying: `.message span` without the right arrow?

Comment: `.message > span` meatches `span` tags that are immediate child of `.message`, `.message span` matches that all descendant `span` tags of `.message`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [CSS3 Attribute Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors):

```
[id$=errors] { ... }
```

This will select any element whose id ends with the value "errors".

Note that browser support is a little iffy.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were trying to have `errors` as a class instead of in ID attribute. You can do:

```
<div class="message">
  <span id="boeing" class="errors">
</div>
```

It would work the CSS selector you already have:

```
.message .errors {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't alter the contents of the span to include a class value so that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your names are invalid. CSS `class` and `id` names should only be alphanumeric values and can include a `-` or `_`. Check the docs for the [full naming convention syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#values).

Drop the `.`, example: `<span id="airbus_errors">`

However, by your CSS, I think what you are meaning to do is share an `errors` class. In which case, this should be your markup:

```
<div class="message">
  <span id="boeing" class="errors">
</div>
```

Comment: The name of the ids are not controlled by me. They're always going to be `something.errors`. But I want to change their background color with a single rule.

Comment: @hunter - you have a doc link to back that up?

Comment: CSS classes must be declared using "." at the beginning.

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated my answer with a link. Looks like I still acquired a downvote though.

Comment: @Jason - see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names for a complete list of characters you can use. You can use `_` or `-`

Comment: @Jason, I didn't down vote you, but I will give you +1 since you were more right than the OP

Comment: @hunter, LOL. Thanks. I wasn't accusing. I just think the drive-by  downvoters are lame.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work for both, then you need to give them a common class. IDs are unique, so you'd have to specify `#airbus.errors, #boeing.errors {...}`, etc. To do it in one CSS rule you need to give them both a common class such as `errors`.

```
.message .errors {
    background: red;
}

<div class="message">
    <span id="airbus" class="errors">
</div>

<div class="message">
    <span id="boeing" class="errors">
</div>
```

If you can't make it a class for some reason, then you have no choice but to be explicit and set it for each ID unless you use CSS3 attribute selectors.

```
.message #airbus.errors,
.message #boeing.errors {
    background: red;
}
```

If you're developing for browsers which support CSS3 (so not IE), then you can achieve what you want with this, (see [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) for more info)

```
.message span[id$="errors"] {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the contents of the span - which is injected by another process so all I have to work with is a bunch of IDs.

Comment: In that case, your choices are either CSS3, or to explicitly specify all the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try the attribute selector and its variations

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Template</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="message">
<span id="airbus.errors">airbus</span>
</div>

<div class="message">
<span id="boeing.errors">boeing</span>
</div>

<div class="message">
<span id="something.errors">something</span>
</div>

<div class="message">
<span id="no.error">error</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
[id$=".errors"]
{
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much you can do, especially cross-browser, to fix that kind of ugly CSS. I see one really portable alternative, and that's this JavaScript:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
     var id = spans[i].id;
     if(id && id.length > 7 && id.substring(id.length - 7) === '.errors') {
          spans[i].id = id.substring(0, id.length - 7);
          spans[i].className = spans[i].className ? spans[i].className + ' errors' : 'errors';
     }
}
```

You could then refer to your elements as `span.errors` in your CSS selector. This is really not a good solution, but then again, there's not much else you can do. If the IDs have to stay the same, just remove the `spans[i].id = ...` line. If they absolutely can't have a class then you can use some fancy JavaScript to read the CSS selector and apply inline styles based on that, too.